# Stuck in selecting columns using regex (in wazuh decoder)

Tags: regular-expression

I have this log but I don't know how to select few columns.

```
04.07.2021 12:11:31.801 [25760] info  MainForm  -  Database(s) loaded: CA_2021,beforetest,FL_2,FL_Jan_2021,jhon,DC_City_Jan_2021,Statetest,Benchmark_2021
```

I used `(\d\d\d\d) (\d+:\d+:\d+)` and able to select

```
2021 12:11:31
```

Can anyone help on selecting

```
2021 12:11:31 [25760] info FL_Jan_2021 DC_City_Jan_2021 Benchmark_2021
```

https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/ruleset/ruleset-xml-syntax/regex.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following custom decoder to extract all fields:

```
<decoder name="log1">
  <prematch>^\d\d.\d\d.\d\d\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d [\d+]\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+- </prematch>
  <regex>^(\d\d.\d\d.\d\d\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d) [(\d+)]\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+-\s+(\.+):\s+(\S+),(\S+),(\S+),(\S+),(\S+),(\S+),(\S+),(\S+)</regex>
  <order>decoded.date,decoded.pid,decoded.type,decoded.source,decoded.action,field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8</order>
</decoder>
```

Where the fields you mention are extracted as `decoded.date`, `decoded.pid`, `decoded.type`, `field4`, `field6` and `field8` respectively. If you don't wish to extract the other fields you may remove their parenthesis on the `<regex>` tag and their names from the `<order>` tag.

The result of running your log through the `wazuh-logtest` utility after configuring this decoder in `/var/ossec/etc/decoders/local_decoders.xml` is:

```
**Phase 1: Completed pre-decoding.
    full event: '14.07.2021 12:11:31.801 [25760] info  MainForm  -  Database(s) loaded: CA_2021,beforetest,FL_2,FL_Jan_2021,jhon,DC_City_Jan_2021,Statetest,Benchmark_2021'

**Phase 2: Completed decoding.
    name: 'log1'
    decoded.action: ' Database(s) loaded'
    decoded.date: '14.07.2021 12:11:31.801'
    decoded.pid: '25760'
    decoded.source: 'MainForm'
    decoded.type: 'info'
    field1: 'CA_2021'
    field2: 'beforetest'
    field3: 'FL_2'
    field4: 'FL_Jan_2021'
    field5: 'jhon'
    field6: 'DC_City_Jan_2021'
    field7: 'Statetest'
    field8: 'Benchmark_2021'
```